# How does EF applies migrations on a database?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an app with 4 environments: DEV, QA, Stage and Production.
When I deployed to the Stage environment, the order of the migrations that were applied was not respected. What could cause this ?

DEV + QA Migration History table:

```
20220607093209_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotes
20220607114458_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInOrders
20220607121426_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotesError
20220617074932_ChangeQuoteStatusPriority
20220617133432_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotes
20220617133916_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInOrders
20220617134335_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotesError
20220620095114_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInQuotes2
20220620103237_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInQuotesError2
20220620103455_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInOrders2
```

Stage + Production:

```
20220620095114_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInQuotes2
20220620103237_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInQuotesError2
20220620103455_UpdateNameEquipmentTypeNameInOrders2
20220607093209_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotes
20220607114458_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInOrders
20220607121426_UpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotesError
20220617074932_ChangeQuoteStatusPriority
20220617133432_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotes
20220617133916_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInOrders
20220617134335_RevertUpdateEquipmentTypesNameInQuotesError
```

As you can see, in the Stage + Production environments, the order of the migrations are somewhat mixed up.
Maybe one thing to note is that we did an upgrade of EF Core versions. We went from 3.1.25 to 6.0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in the table doesn't necessarily represent the order they were applied. If they were all applied in one transaction, SQL Server could have shuffled the order of the rows around when inserting them.

Comment: Hi @bricelam, good to see you here. Isn't it recommended to use `dotnet ef migration script [start_from_migration]` in order to deploy your database to a production environment, or is that just one of the options?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bricealm. That seems like an error prone thing to do. Is there something that could be done to mitigate this? I was trying to execute the migrations on a PostgreSQL server.

Comment: @Pieterjan As always, it depends. See [Applying Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for our detailed guidance.

Comment: @Sebastian Most databases don't guarantee row order. You mitigate it by looking at the data with an ORDER BY clause in your SQL.